# Article where boolean is false and attribute is present - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an `Article` model with an `approved?` boolean and a `short_answer` text column.

What is the best way to find an article where approved is false and the short_answer is present?

I know you can check two conditions using something like this:

```
Article.where(:approved => false, :short_answer => "")
```

but not sure how to assure that the short_answer is `present?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to find an article where approved is false and
>   the short_answer is present?

You could write [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for individual condition so that you could reuse in future as well.

```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      scope :all_approved, -> { where(approved: false) }
      scope :all_short_answer, -> { where("articles.short_answer IS NOT NULL") }
   end

   Article.all_approved.all_short_answer
```

Now there are multiple way to write query with where clauses. I'm going to dispense to you now and it up to you which religion you want to subscribe to.

**1.** You could use raw SQL query in where clauses like

```
scope :all_short_answer, -> { where("short_answer IS NOT NULL") }`
```

**2.** Could rewrite `all_short_answer` scope as

`scope :all_short_answer, -> { where(articles.short_answer != nil) }`

**3.** Could uses [where.not](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)

`scope :all_short_answer, -> { where.not('articles.short_answer' => nil) }`

Comment: @WizardofOgz Went for **Coffee**Nope Its not . Have I Said that  ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this (work with Rails 3.2 or later):

```
Article.where(approved: false).
  where('aticles.short_answer IS NOT NULL')
```

Or this (only with ActiveRecord 4 or later):

```
Article.where(approved: false).
  where.not(short_answer: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@article = Article.where(approved: false).where.not(short_answer: nil).first
```

If you wanted to scope it:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :approved_short_answer, -> { where(approved:false).where.not(short_answer: nil).first }
end

@article = Article.approved_short_answer
```

Answer (score -1):

The Rails `present?` helper returns `false` if the field is either NULL *or* contains an empty string (`""`). It returns `true` if the string contains one or more characters. Therefore it's not enough to test if `short_answer` is `nil`.

So, for Rails 4.x:

```
Article.where(approved: false).where('length(short_answer) > 0')
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to find the Articles for which

- approved = false
- short_answer != null
- short_answer != "" (empty string)

which you can do through ActiveRecord Query Interface

```
Article
  .where(approved: false)
  .where.not(short_answer: nil)
  .where.not(short_answer: "")
```

This can be simplified if you can guarantee that all non-null values for `short_answer` will contain text.

```
Article
  .where(approved: false)
  .where.not(short_answer: nil)
```